# How to use orderBy and where clause together in Laravel5 ORM

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel5 I need to put orderBy and where clause together, as in:

```
$patches = Patch::orderBy('PatchCode', 'DESC')
    ->where('AccountID', '=', Auth::user()->AccountID)->get();
```

But orderBy is not working. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you edit your question by adding dd($patch) ? What is your DB schema like?

Comment: Try orderBy at the end `$patches = Patch::where('AccountID', '=', Auth::user()->AccountID)->orderBy('PatchCode', 'DESC')->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which will definitely work. Just put the orderBy at the end. Like:

```
$patches = Patch::where('AccountID', '=', Auth::user()->AccountID)
->orderBy('PatchCode', 'DESC')
->get();
```